# Grep IP Address within Class B networks only

Tags: regex, linux, grep

`172.16.0.0/12` is a Class B networks. I would like to grep IP from this Class only.

Here is the sample log file.

```
[user@linux ~]$ cat ClassB.txt
172.16.0.0/12 is a Class B networks
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
Network:    172.16.0.0/12
HostMin:        172.16.0.1
HostMax:        172.31.255.254
Broadcast:      172.31.255.255
Out of range:   172.32.255.254
Out of range:   172.15.0.1
Out of range:   172.4.0.1
[user@linux ~]$
```

If I use `egrep -n '172.[1-3][0-9]' ClassB.txt`, this will grep `172.32.255.254` as well which is out of Class B range.

```
[user@linux ~]$ egrep -n '172.[1-3][0-9]' ClassB.txt
1:172.16.0.0/12 is a Class B networks
2:172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
3:Network:              172.16.0.0/12
4:HostMin:              172.16.0.1
5:HostMax:              172.31.255.254
6:Broadcast:            172.31.255.255
7:Class B:              172.19.0.1
8:Class B:              172.20.0.1
9:Out of range:         172.32.255.254
10:Out of range:        172.15.0.1
[user@linux ~]$
```

What should I do to grep only Class B IP Address only which is from `172.16.0.0` to `172.31.255.255`

**Desired Output**

```
[user@linux ~]$ <grep/egrep command here> ClassB.txt
1:172.16.0.0/12 is a Class B networks
2:172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
3:Network:              172.16.0.0/12
4:HostMin:              172.16.0.1
5:HostMax:              172.31.255.254
6:Broadcast:            172.31.255.255
7:Class B:              172.19.0.1
8:Class B:              172.20.0.1
[user@linux ~]$
```

Comment: `grep -E '\b172(\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|32\.0\.0)\b' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do is this

```
grep "172\.\(1[6-9]\|2[0-9]\|3[01]\)\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}" ClassB.txt
```

but getting the answer is not getting a solution, so let me explain.  Using double quotes or single is a form of choice, and the nuance is in the escaping.  I tend to use double, but the single form is exactly the same in this example.

```
grep  '172\.\(1[6-9]\|2[0-9]\|3[01]\)\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' ClassB.txt
```

This regex assumes the input is validated, ie you dont have an ip address that is out of bounds.  like say 172.31.555.1.  This simplifies it from the validating grep expression

```
grep  "172\.\(1[6-9]\|2[0-9]\|3[01]\)\.\([0-9]\.\|[1]\{,1\}[0-9]\{2\}\.\|2[0-4][0-9]\.\|25[0-5]\.\)\([0-9]\|[1]\{,1\}[0-9]\{2\}\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)" ClassB.txt
```

edit: I forgot my explanation

the validating answer has 3 subgroups

```
\(1[6-9]\|2[0-9]\|3[01]\)\.
\([0-9]\.\|[1]\{,1\}[0-9]\{2\}\.\|2[0-4][0-9]\.\|25[0-5]\.\)
\([0-9]\|[1]\{,1\}[0-9]\{2\}\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)
```

and they relate to the three ending parts of the ip address, you could replace the second with the third and follow it with a \. and it would technically be the same, as there are often many regex that work but look totally different. I normally choose the first one that is simpler, because most input is validated, if it isnt it requires validation regex.

If for instance you just wanted all ip addresses a much simpler regex would be

```
grep "\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}" ClassB.txt
```

again this would require that the input be prevalidated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the nuance is in the escaping"?

Comment: escaping strategies are different for double quotes and single quotes.  some of them are the same, but some of them are different.  some escaping that has to be done in a double quotes scenario, can be done as well in a single quote scenario, but isn't necessary.  escaping strings in bash is sort of an artform.